# How do eliminate the vertical space between div tags

Tags: javascript, html

A sample html which contains 4 div tags, which first one has few html controls and second and third div was only used for status display based on the condition. The fourth one was used for the submit button.

The first and second one by default visibility was hidden. However, It has taken vertical space hence my submit button position has some empty space. How can I reduce that space ?

My Code:

```
<!-- Div 1 -->
<div>
<!-- few controls goes here -->
</div>

<!-- Div 2 -->
<div style="visibility:hidden">
<asp:CompareValidator ID="valPwd" validationgroup="valRegGroup" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Passwords don't match" CssClass="validation" ControlToCompare="txtPwd" ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPwd"></asp:CompareValidator>
</div>

<!-- Div 3 -->
<div style="visibility:hidden">
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="validation"></asp:Label>
</div>   

<!-- Div 4 -->
<div style="top:0px;margin-top:0px;">
<asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Renew" 
  CssClass="SubmitButton" onclick="btnValidate_Click"  />                     
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting `display: none` that way the `div`'s don't take any room in the layout.

When displaying your status or other data, set `display: block` to make it visible.

Using `visibility: hidden` hides the element but retains the its space and position within the layout.

To read about the `visibility` property, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#visibility

To read about the `display` property, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="display:none">
```

will solve your problem

display and visibility are different style properties

Answer (score 0):

try `display:none` insted of `visibility:hidden`

for validators use `display:dynamic` property to reduce the space

another scenario if you are unable to chnage your and make the modification try using the below css selectors to reduce the space

```
div[style*="visible"] {  
 display:inline;
    }  

div[style*="hidden"] {  
      display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> style="display:none">

instead of

> style="visibility:hidden"

This way no space will be left for the element that is not displayed.